# Should PgBouncer be installed on web application server or database server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgbouncer

I have a django website where the application and database server are different. I need to install pgbouncer to enable database pooling, however, I'm confused about where to install it: web application server or database server?

Note that in this set up, there is exactly 1 application server and 1 database server.

Comment: To decide where `pgBouncer` can be installed, it depends on your resources and performance.  Our company installed `pgBouncer` on a `stand-alone` server (same network with application and database server) because we don't want to share resources of `applications & database server` with `pgBouncer`. However, if you have only two servers. I think you should consider about resources usage on two servers before installing `pgBouncer` (you can do several `load-tests` when installed it on `application server` or `database server`).

Comment: @LuanHuynh how much resources pgBouncer can possibly use?  We have it on some DB hosts, and never realized it had a performance hit, but it's also possible we were looking at the wrong place.

Comment: guys, my perspective on it has now gone on the opposite end of the spectrum. Can you quickly skim this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/759377/321109 It makes sense to me. What do you guys think?

Comment: @dezso: In fact, in production environment (Google CLoud), we have two test cases related to installed `pgBouncer`. Case 1: it is installed same `DB host` and case 2: it is installed in a `standalone server`. Then we do some `load-tests` over `10...3000` concurrent users. As a result, we choose installed `pgBouncer`in a `standalone server` to increase resources (RAM, CPU)  for  `DB`.  However, in development env, we are still using `pgBouncer` in the same `DB host`, it works fine.

Comment: @HassanBaig: I think you can installed `pgBouncer` in the same `DB host`, then do some `load-test` with your application. You can use `jMeter`.

Comment: @HassanBaig: you should consider `prepare statement` on your application before using `pgBouncer`. Our developers had to update severa application because it generates `prepare command` to `DB` via `pgBouncer` (we try to modify pgBouncer but it can't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend first installing it on the database server.  That way you can run `top` (or whatever) on that machine and have a one-stop-shop to see what is going on.  Also, the dependencies are more likely to already be installed on the database server than they are on the application server.

If you then notice the database server is more heavily loaded than the app server, you can move it to the app server.  But looking at the current loads (when you don't have connection pooling in place) to make that decision isn't going to be terribly useful, because they could change dramatically once you start pooling.

Answer (score 2):

This is a official FAQ from pgbouncer web site:

[WEB vs DB](https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html#should-pgbouncer-be-installed-on-webserver-or-database-server)